# How to add a filtered array to a model in Emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a list of products I am rendering as a component.

This is my template

```
<p>{{product.name}}</p>
<p>{{product.description}}</p>
<p>{{product.price}}</p>
<p>{{product.productCategory.id}}</p>
{{#product-line-item product.lineItems}}
{{/product-line-item}}
```

I am trying to pass a filtered array (product.lineItems) to a component so I can indicate the quantity for each product that is in the cart. What I am trying to do in the model seems incorrect.

Here is my attempt at creating an array on the product model for lineItems that belong to that product:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      products: this.store.findAll('product'),
      productCategories: this.store.findAll('productCategory'),
      lineItems: this.store.queryRecord('lineItem', { user_id: this.get('session.secure.user_id') })
    }).then(function (model) {
      model.products.forEach(function(product){
        product.lineItems = [];
        model.lineItems.forEach(function(lineItem) {
          if (lineItem.productId === product.id) {
            product.lineItems.pushObject(lineItem);
          }
        })
      });
      return model
    });
  }
});
```

Firstly, each product ends up having an empty lineItems array.

Secondly this doesn't feel right. Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Check my answer and if it doesn't work please provide code for model definitions of `lineItem` and `product` with sample response for `products` and `lineItems` request in `RSVP.hash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would have `lineItems` belong to `product`. However it's possible to do what you need without changing relations between models. However I need to assume few things:

- all 3 requests/promises resolve with not empty arrays
- `lineItem` has property `productId` which matches some `product.id`, so filter will work correctly

Try this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      products: this.store.findAll('product'),
      productCategories: this.store.findAll('productCategory'),
      lineItems: this.store.queryRecord('lineItem', { user_id: this.get('session.secure.user_id') })
    }).then(model => {
      model.products.forEach(product => {
        let lineItems = [];
        model.lineItems.forEach(lineItem => {
          if (lineItem.get('productId') === product.get('id')) {
            lineItems.pushObject(lineItem);
          }
        })
        product.set('lineItems', lineItems);
      });
      return model;
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated code. I was making it overcomplicated. I simply declare a new property on each product called numberOfLineItems and assign the quantity if applicable, otherwise 0.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      products: this.store.findAll('product'),
      productCategories: this.store.findAll('productCategory'),
      lineItems: this.store.queryRecord('lineItem', { user_id: this.get('session.secure.user_id') })
    })
  },
  afterModel: function(model) {
    model.products.forEach(function(product){
      // product.lineItems = [];
      product.numberOfLineItems = 0
      model.lineItems.forEach(function(lineItem) {
        if (lineItem.get('product.id') === product.id) {
          product.numberOfLineItems = lineItem.get('quantity');
        }
      })
    });
    return model
  }
});
```